# CSS3 анимация. Изменение направления движения + зацикливание

Tags: css3, анимация

На просторах интернета нашел любопытный эффект для изображений.
Но моих познаний в верстке мало, чтобы изменить направление движения градиента (сверху-вниз на слева-направо) и зациклить ее, то есть вызов не по наведению на картинку.

```css
figure {
  width: 314px;
  height: 271px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -120%;
  transition: top 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
figure:hover {
  top: 120%;
}
figure:before, figure:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
figure:before {
  width: 100%;
  top: inherit;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #ffffff 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
figure:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/ws/660/amz/worldservice/live/assets/images/2015/09/02/150902003640_google_624x351_google_nocredit.jpg");
}
section {
  width: 100%
  text-align: center;
}
body{
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<figure></figure>
```

Буду рад за помощь в данном вопросе!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для создания анимации используется свойство `animation`. Оно позволит настроить  продолжительность анимации и количество повторении анимации.

`@keyframes` определяет внешний вид анимации. Это делается с помощью ключей после `@keyframes`. Каждый ключ описывает где должен находиться анимированный элемент в данный момент.

В вашем случае создается дубликат картинки в `figure:before`, который анимируется прохождением поверх оригинальной картинки, за счет этого получается эффект. Чтоб изменить эффект нужно поменять анимацию `figure:before`, что я и сделал в примере.

`animation: [имя анимации из @keyframes] [время одного цикла анимации] [количество повторении анимации, значение infinite для бесконечного повторения анимации];`

Подробнее: [MDN Использование CSS анимации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Ispolzovanie_CSS_animatciy)

```css
figure {
  width: 314px;
  height: 271px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
figure:before,
figure:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
figure:before {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #ffffff 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  
  animation: effect 1s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/ws/660/amz/worldservice/live/assets/images/2015/09/02/150902003640_google_624x351_google_nocredit.jpg");
}

@keyframes effect {
  from {
    left: -120%;
  }

  to {
    left: 120%;
  }
}
```

```html
<figure></figure>
```